# default rows from select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query (Oracle database) with group by clause that needs to return 4 rows if all required data exist. It works perfectly.
How can I write a select query that returns same 4 rows even if no data exist. I want the field C value to be zero if no data. Please let know. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like?  What is the query you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select x.a, x.b, count(t.a)
from (select 'ORG-1' as A, 'CAR' as b from dual union all
      select 'ORG-1' as A, 'BIKE' as b from dual union all
      select 'ORG-2' as A, 'CAR' as b from dual union all
      select 'ORG-2' as A, 'BIKE' as b from dual 
     ) x left join
     t
     on x.a = t.a and x.b = t.b
group by x.a, x.b
```

Comment: Query I tried below.

select b.org, a.status, count(*)
from (select 'ORG-1' as A1, 'CAR' as B1 from dual union all
      select 'ORG-1' as A1, 'BIKE' as B1 from dual union all
      select 'ORG-2' as A1, 'CAR' as B1 from dual union all
      select 'ORG-2' as A1, 'BIKE' as B1 from dual 
     )  X left join vchlschdl a on X.A1=a.A1 and X.B1=a.B1
          left join vchlmstr b on a.servers=b.servers
group by X.A1,X.B1

Comment: @user3166984 . . . You should get all four rows with that query.